# Creating Circular thumbnails in PIL on a certain position

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have been working on a python file that greets users based upon their profile pictures + name. I managed to put their name in the required area but i am having issues in pasting a circular profile picture in the given place.

Here's how it should look like

[input.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76A6U.jpg)

Input
  Profile Picture

[profilepicture.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GSgE.png)

Output

[output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT18k.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is the 'mask' argument of Image.paste - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste - 'If a mask is given, this method updates only the regions indicated by the mask.'

So that allows us to create an image of a circle to only paste the relevant part of the profile picture.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

background = Image.open('input.jpg')
im = Image.open('profilepicture.png')

# Scale the image to be the size of the circle
im = im.resize((1024, 1024), Image.ANTIALIAS)

# Create the circle mask
mask = Image.new('L', im.size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse((0, 0) + im.size, fill=255)

background.paste(im, (410, 1104), mask)
background.save('output.png')
```